# how to fix black video streaming on ios - kurento

Tags: webrtc, kurento, video-conferencing, webrtc-ios, kurento-media-server

i have a video conference app built in nodejs and kurento.

when i connect my camera on desktop/Android everything is ok.

when i connect camera on iphone, i can see the shared video on iphone (locally) very well, but the camera on other devices (receiving devices) in the room stays black and doesn't show up.

my client code:

```js
const videoConstraints = {};
videoConstraints.facingMode = 'environment';
const constraints = {
  video: videoConstraints,
  audio: false
};
            
receiveMediaLocal(token, 'webcam', socket.id, constraints)
setTimeout(() => {
  iKurentoClient.sendMessage({ ...data, type: 'video', mode: 'webcam', id:         'connectMedia' })
}, 100)

function receiveMediaLocal(sender, mode, connId, constraints, mediaScreen = null) {
        
        var participant = new Participant(this, sender, mode, connId);
        if (!this.participants[sender]) this.participants[sender] = {};
        this.participants[sender][mode] = participant;
        var media = participant.getMediaElement();
        var options = {
            localVideo: media,
            mediaConstraints: constraints,
            onicecandidate: participant.onIceCandidate.bind(participant)
        }
        
        
        participant.rtcPeer = new kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendonly(options,
            function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    this.socket.emit("error",error);
                    return console.error(error);
                }
                this.generateOffer(participant.offerToReceiveMedia.bind(participant));
            }
        );
    }
```

how can i fix this bug?
thank you.

Comment: Same here! Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need put this in your client html

```
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

While implementations of WebRTC in browsers are still evolving due to varying levels of support for WebRTC features, we can avoid issues with compatibility by making use of the Adapter.js library.